# Unusual Vim Auto-completion Feature

Tags: autocompletion

Usually, in Vim, pressing `<TAB>` autocompletes a command. For example, typing

```
:set <TAB>
```

will autocomplete to `:set all`. Pressing `<TAB>` again will autocomplete to `:set termcap`.

However, on one specific Kubuntu 17.04 machine I own, pressing tab shows something like this:
[image: Gray bar with list of options and highlighted yellow selection.]

**How can I enable/disable this functionality in Vim? What is this feature called?**

My `vim --version` is this:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Mar 17 2017 12:13:35)
Included patches: 1-95
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
+arabic          +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
+autocmd         +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tcl
-balloon_eval    +folding         +mouse_xterm     +termguicolors
-browse          -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
++builtin_terms  +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+byte_offset     +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
+channel         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +timers
+cindent         +iconv           +num64           +title
-clientserver    +insert_expand   +packages        -toolbar
-clipboard       +job             +path_extra      +user_commands
+cmdline_compl   +jumplist        -perl            +vertsplit
+cmdline_hist    +keymap          +persistent_undo +virtualedit
+cmdline_info    +lambda          +postscript      +visual
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visualextra
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +viminfo
+cryptv          +linebreak       -python          +vreplace
+cscope          +lispindent      +python3         +wildignore
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildmenu
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +windows
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +writebackup
+diff            +menu            -ruby            -X11
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -xfontset
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xim
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xpm
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      +startuptime     -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax
+farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -Wdate-time  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/vim-8krYYf/vim-8.0.0095=. -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux  -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl     -L/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.5m -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm
```

My system vimrc is this (comments removed for brevity):

```
runtime! debian.vim
if has("syntax")
  syntax on
endif
if filereadable("/etc/vim/vimrc.local")
  source /etc/vim/vimrc.local
endif
```

I don't have a user vimrc. As far as I know, this is the stock install of vim for Ubuntu 17.04 (`sudo apt-get install vim`) with no extra options or added plugins. It's possible that Ubuntu ships Vim with plugins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the [`wildmenu`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27wildmenu%27) setting that lists all the options. The [`wildmode`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27wildmode%27) setting can also affect the specific behavior of completion in command-line mode, including when the wildmenu will appear.

`wildmenu` requires that Vim was compiled with the `+wildmenu` option, which appears to be the case for the particular version text you've provided. `wildmode` does not appear to be dependent on any compilation flags, so there may be some builds of Vim that can do command-line completion, but cannot show the full menu.

You can use `:verbose set wildmenu?` to see where `wildmenu` was last set from.

Comment: Thank you some much for this! Looking for this ultra-cool feature was driving me crazy. This is my first question on Vi/Vim Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is enabled by the [wildmenu setting](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27wildmenu%27) which is enabled in the [defaults.vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/defaults.vim#L41) file. So if you **do not** have a vimrc file, vim will automatically load the defaults.vim file, which sets some options to enable an easier Vim experience.

Read the help at [:h defaults.vim](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#defaults.vim) for all the details.